# How to run specific TestSuite or TestCase from Soapui using java?

Tags: java, soapui

After I have create a project in soapui, now I want to run specific TestSuites and TestCases from my project, here I found an example with google but it execute all the TestSuites in the Project.

How can I specify the name of TestSuite and TestCase that I want to run?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.support.PropertiesMap;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCase;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestSuite;

public class TestRunnerSample {

  @Test
  public void fullControl() throws Exception {

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:/Folder/Project.xml");
    List<TestSuite> testSuites = project.getTestSuiteList();

    for( TestSuite suite : testSuites ) {
    List<TestCase> testCases = suite.getTestCaseList();

      for( TestCase testCase : testCases ) {
        System.out.println("Running SoapUI test [" + testCase.getName() + "]");
        TestRunner runner2 = testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);
        assertEquals(Status.FINISHED, runner2.getStatus());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the official documentation? http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject` API](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject.html), there is a [`getTestSuiteByName(String testSuiteName)`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject.html#getTestSuiteByName(java.lang.String)) method to get the TestSuite by it's name, this method returns a [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlTestSuite.html) object which also has [`getTestCaseByName(String testCaseName)`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlTestSuite.html#getTestCaseByName(java.lang.String)) method to get a TestCase inside this TestSuite by name.

You can run both the TestSuite (`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite`) or a specific TestCase (`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase`) using `run(StringToObjectMap properties, boolean async)` method as you do in your code sample.

Using your code you can do something as:

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:/Folder/Project.xml");
WsdlTestSuite ts = project.getTestSuiteByName('myTestSuite');
WsdlTestCase tc = ts.getTestCaseByName('myTestCase');

System.out.println("Running SoapUI test [" + tc.getName() + "]");
// run a specific testCase
TestRunner tcRunner = tc.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);
assertEquals(Status.FINISHED, tcRunner.getStatus());

// or alternatively run the whole TestSuite
TestRunner tsRunner = ts.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);
assertEquals(Status.FINISHED, tsRunner.getStatus());
...
```

Hope this helps,